# Como fazer um botão piscar?

Tags: java, swing

Criei um código simples para um jogo similar ao Genius, onde um botão aleatório de um conjunto de 20 botões começa a piscar, porém eu não consigo um intervalo para que a mudança de cor seja visível...

Segue um exemplo, basicamente, eu só preciso que a cor do botão troque aleatoriamente, de 0,3 em 0,3 seg...

```
try{
    for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++){ 

        //define a proxima cor aleatoria
        cor1 = (int)(Math.random()*255)+1;

        //deveria gerar o atraso de 0,3s
        Thread.sleep(300);

        jButton1.setBackground(new Color (cor1,00,00));

    }

}catch (InterruptedExcepetion e){}
```

Comment: Se ao invés de trocar a cor, colocar um gif de background? Será resolve?

Comment: Mas se for pra fazer do jeito que vc quer, vc deverá colocar essa mudança de cor em um thred, para swing eu recomendaria um SwingWorker. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/swingworker-137249.html

Comment: Ok, vlw pela dica.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu faria da seguinte forma:

- Um Java Swing Timer para controlar todo o processo
- A cada 0,3s é despoletado um evento que processas através de um ActionListener
- No ActionListener escolhes a cor de forma aleatória e alteras o botão

Aqui segue um pequeno exemplo de como podes fazer:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Example extends JFrame
{
    private JButton button;
    private Timer timer;
    private int delay = 300; // a cada 0,3 segundos
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    Random rand = new Random();

    public SimpleTimer()
    {
        super("Teste");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        button = new JButton("O meu botão");
        JPanel contentPane = (JPanel) getContentPane();
        contentPane.add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contentPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        pack();

        ActionListener action = new ActionListener()
        {   
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                    float r = rand.nextFloat();
                    float g = rand.nextFloat();
                    float b = rand.nextFloat();

                    button.setBackground(new Color(r, g, b));
            }
        };

        timer = new Timer(delay, action);
        timer.setInitialDelay(0);
        timer.start();

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new SimpleTimer();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Genial a sua ideia, me sinto um bocado inexperiente e não ter pensado nela antes :/ 
Muito obrigado, resolveu excelentemente o meu problema :D :D